# Add to array only if there isn't a key with the same value?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add `$variable` only if there isn't a key with the same value in array `$insertar["Atributos"]`.

```
$insertar["Atributos"][] = $variable;
```

I can do it using a foreach to check beforehand if `$variable` is stored and insert only if it isn't but I want to know if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear:

**I want to add `$variable` only if there isn't a key with the same value in array `$insertar["Atributos"]`.**

```php
# check if $variable exists as a value in $insertar["Atributos"], and not a key
if (in_array($variable, $insertar["Atributos"])) {
    # add $variable as a VALUE to the array
    $insertar["Atributos"][] = $variable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I read the question wrong.  Try if (! [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)($value, $array)) { ... }

At first I thought you meant if the value is a key.  If you want to check if a key is in an array use `isset($array[$key])` rather than `array_key_exists` because isset will perform much faster on long arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative cleanup and post-processing approach:

```
$insertar = array_map("array_unique", $insertar);
```

See [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique). Implicitly orders the value entries however.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple construct like this:

```
if(! in_array($variable, $insertar["Atributos"])){
    array_push($variable,$insertar["Atributos"]);
}
```